# TSQL Pivot with Multiple Columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I need to dynamically set up a pivot table for contacts.  I do not know how many rows each person will have.   I am using a STU_ID as a primary key and name.   I want the result to show one student for a year with all their contacts as columns. All information is made up.

```
-- Create Table 
CREATE TABLE parentContact
(
    STU_ID VARCHAR(10),
    SCH_YEAR VARCHAR(4),
    STU_LastName VARCHAR(50),
    STU_FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    Series INT, 
    P_FirstName VARCHAR(50),
    P_MiddName VARCHAR(50),
    P_LastName VARCHAR(50),
    P_HomePhone VARCHAR(15),
    P_CellPhone VARCHAR(15),
    P_email VARCHAR(100),
    RelationShip_Flag INT,
)
```

```
INSERT INTO parentContact (STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName, Series, P_FirstName, P_MiddName, P_LastName,P_HomePhone, P_CellPhone, P_email, RelationShip_Flag)
VALUES
('10225', '2023', 'Doe', 'John', 1, 'Lisa','Luis','Doe','1-555-250-1588', '1-555-250-8954', 'somebody@hotmail.com', 9),
('10225', '2023', 'Doe', 'John', 2, 'Gina','Lee','Doe',NULL, '1-555-250-7521', 'SecondBoday@gmail.com', 4),
('10225', '2022', 'Doe', 'John', 1, 'Gina','Lee','Doe',NULL, '1-555-250-7521', 'SecondBoday@gmail.com', 4),
('10225', '2023', 'Doe', 'John', 3, 'Bobby','Derick','Smith',NULL, '1-555-250-4513', 'loousman@gmail.com', 8),
('10721', '2023', 'Brown', 'Jennifer', 1, 'Johnny','Robbert','Smith',NULL, '1-555-155-4513', Null, 9),
('10721', '2023', 'Brown', 'Jennifer', 2, 'Danny','Flipions','Brown',NULL, '1-555-155-4919', Null, 9),
('10523', '2023', 'Johnson', 'Michael', 1, 'Cindy','Dawn','Johnson',NULL, '1-555-250-7100', 'cd@aol.com', 9),
('10422', '2023', 'Que', 'Suzi', 1, 'Martha','Ding','Que','1-555-251-1581', '1-555-251-1581', 'MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com', 9),
('10422', '2022', 'Que', 'Suzi', 1, 'Martha','Ding','Que','1-555-251-1581', '1-555-251-1581', 'MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com', 9),
('10422', '2021', 'Que', 'Suzi', 1, 'Martha','Ding','Que','1-555-251-1581', '1-555-251-1581', 'MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com', 9),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 1, 'Lupita','Sing','Perez','1-555-251-0051', '1-555-251-9925', 'persez@gmail.com', 9),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 2, 'Juan','Gonzlez','Perez','1-555-251-0051', '1-555-251-8741', 'perez.jaun@gmail.com', 9),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 3, 'George','Pedro','Perez',NULL, '1-555-250-6002', NULL, 8),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 4, 'Linda','Julica','Perez',NULL, '1-555-250-1111', 'julic@microsoft.com', 8),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 5, 'Mathew','Dee','SomeBody',NULL, '1-555-250-2556', 'Sombody@microsoft.com', 7),
('12001', '2023', 'Perez', 'Roberto', 6, 'Jascila','Roberta','Gonzlez', '1-555-251-2252', '1-555-251-5557', 'robertaG@aol.com', 7);
```

```
-- My attempt at the columns 
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Get the list of distinct contact numbers dynamically
SET @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME('Contact' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)))
    FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName ORDER BY Series) AS ContactNumber
        FROM parentContact
    ) AS NumberedContacts
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

--the dynamic query
SET @query = '
SELECT STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName, ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName,
           P_FirstName + '' '' + ISNULL(P_MiddName + '' '', '''') + '' '' + P_LastName AS PersonName,
           P_HomePhone AS PersonPhone,
           P_CellPhone AS PersonCell,
           P_email AS PersonEmail,
           RelationShip_Flag AS RelationFlag,
           ''Contact'' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ContactNameColumn,
           ''Phone'' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ContactPhoneColumn,
           ''Cell'' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ContactCellColumn,
           ''Email'' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ContactEmailColumn,
           ''RelationFlag'' + CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS ContactRelationFlagColumn
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName ORDER BY Series) AS ContactNumber,
        P_CellPhone AS PersonPhone -- Add an alias for P_CellPhone here
        FROM parentContact
    ) AS NumberedContacts
) AS src
PIVOT (
    MAX(PersonName) AS FirstName, MAX(PersonPhone) AS PhoneNumber,
    MAX(PersonCell) AS CellPhoneNumber, MAX(PersonEmail) AS Email,
    MAX(RelationFlag) AS RelationFlag
    FOR ContactNameColumn IN (' + @cols + ')
) AS piv';

-- Execute the dynamic query
--PRINT @query;
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

I know I have not put a filter in for years yet... cannot get full table to work. Please help.

I am expecting a table that is like this. I know my current code does not have all the columns I was trying to get a subset to work to then go about the whole solution. However, I am getting Syntax errors in the PIVOT statement then the Select then the query.

Yes, the query has to be dynamic because the number of Contact people for a Student is unrestricted can have many more than 6.

```
STU_NUM, SCH_YEAR, STU_FirstName, STU_LastName, 
ContactsName1, CellPhone1, Phone1, email1, contactRel1, 
ContactName2, CellPhone2, ................
```

Comment: Please format your posting properly.  No one is going to read that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot use the `PIVOT` syntax to generate multiple columns per pivot value in SQL server (at least not without creating multiple subqueries, each with its own PIVOT, that are then joined together).

As an alternative, you can use *conditional aggregation* to accomplish your goals. Conditional aggregation uses a `CASE` expression wrapped in an aggregate function to filter the data fed into that function. In this case, you can use `MAX(CASE WHEN ContactNumber = N THEN Value END) AS ValueN`, where `Value` and `N` are replaced by the different column names and pivot values. When the condition is false, the implied ELSE just passes a null into the aggregate, so the aggregate only sees the intended values.

This allows you to generate multiple columns per `ContactNumber` value to produce your desired result. `GROUP BY` is used to define the rows.

Something like:

```
-- My try at the columns 
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Template to generate multiple columns per ContactNumber using conditional aggregation
DECLARE @ColumnsTemplate NVARCHAR(MAX) = ',
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = <N> THEN src.PersonName END) AS Contact<N>,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = <N> THEN src.PersonPhone END) AS Phone<N>,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = <N> THEN src.PersonCell END) AS Cell<N>,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = <N> THEN src.PersonEmail END) AS Email<N>,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = <N> THEN src.RelationFlag END) AS RelationFlag<N>'

-- Get the list of distinct contact numbers dynamically
SET @cols = STUFF((
    SELECT REPLACE(@ColumnsTemplate, '<N>', CAST(ContactNumber AS NVARCHAR(10)))
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName ORDER BY Series) AS ContactNumber
        FROM parentContact
    ) AS NumberedContacts
    ORDER BY ContactNumber
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '');

--PRINT @cols
  
--the dynamic query
SET @query = '
SELECT STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName, ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    SELECT STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName ORDER BY Series) AS ContactNumber,
           P_FirstName + '' '' + ISNULL(P_MiddName + '' '', '''') + '' '' + P_LastName AS PersonName,
           P_HomePhone AS PersonPhone,
           P_CellPhone AS PersonCell,
           P_email AS PersonEmail,
           RelationShip_Flag AS RelationFlag
    FROM parentContact
) AS src
GROUP BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName
ORDER BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName
';

-- Execute the dynamic query
--PRINT @query;
EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

The generated dynamic SQL will look like:

```
SELECT STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 1 THEN src.PersonName END) AS Contact1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 1 THEN src.PersonPhone END) AS Phone1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 1 THEN src.PersonCell END) AS Cell1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 1 THEN src.PersonEmail END) AS Email1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 1 THEN src.RelationFlag END) AS RelationFlag1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN src.ContactNumber = 2 THEN src.PersonName END) AS Contact2,
    ...
FROM (
...
) AS src
GROUP BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName
ORDER BY STU_ID, SCH_YEAR, STU_LastName, STU_FirstName
```

Sample results:

| STU_ID | SCH_YEAR | STU_LastName | STU_FirstName | Contact1 | Phone1 | Cell1 | Email1 | RelationFlag1 | Contact2 | Phone2 | Cell2 | Email2 | RelationFlag2 | Contact3 | Phone3 | Cell3 | Email3 | RelationFlag3 | Contact4 | Phone4 | Cell4 | Email4 | RelationFlag4 | Contact5 | Phone5 | Cell5 | Email5 | RelationFlag5 | Contact6 | Phone6 | Cell6 | Email6 | RelationFlag6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10225 | 2022 | Doe | John | Gina Lee Doe | null | 1-555-250-7521 | SecondBoday@gmail.com | 4 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10225 | 2023 | Doe | John | Lisa Luis Doe | 1-555-250-1588 | 1-555-250-8954 | somebody@hotmail.com | 9 | Gina Lee Doe | null | 1-555-250-7521 | SecondBoday@gmail.com | 4 | Bobby Derick Smith | null | 1-555-250-4513 | loousman@gmail.com | 8 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10422 | 2021 | Que | Suzi | Martha Ding Que | 1-555-251-1581 | 1-555-251-1581 | MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10422 | 2022 | Que | Suzi | Martha Ding Que | 1-555-251-1581 | 1-555-251-1581 | MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10422 | 2023 | Que | Suzi | Martha Ding Que | 1-555-251-1581 | 1-555-251-1581 | MarthaDing@SimpleEmail.com | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10523 | 2023 | Johnson | Michael | Cindy Dawn Johnson | null | 1-555-250-7100 | cd@aol.com | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 10721 | 2023 | Brown | Jennifer | Johnny Robbert Smith | null | 1-555-155-4513 | null | 9 | Danny Flipions Brown | null | 1-555-155-4919 | null | 9 | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null | null |
| 12001 | 2023 | Perez | Roberto | Lupita Sing Perez | 1-555-251-0051 | 1-555-251-9925 | persez@gmail.com | 9 | Juan Gonzlez Perez | 1-555-251-0051 | 1-555-251-8741 | perez.jaun@gmail.com | 9 | George Pedro Perez | null | 1-555-250-6002 | null | 8 | Linda Julica Perez | null | 1-555-250-1111 | julic@microsoft.com | 8 | Mathew Dee SomeBody | null | 1-555-250-2556 | Sombody@microsoft.com | 7 | Jascila Roberta Gonzlez | 1-555-251-2252 | 1-555-251-5557 | robertaG@aol.com | 7 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zI9rptyq) for a working demo.

I simplified the inner query somewhat, but there are opportinutes for further simplifications:

1. I expect you can eliminate most of the column aliasing and just reference the original column names in the conditional aggregation expressions.
2. Depending on your data, you might be able to eliminate `ContactNumber` in favor of `Series`.
3. You might also find the `CONCAT_WS()` function to be useful in concatenating name parts - `CONCAT_WS(' ', P_FirstName, P_MiddName, P_LastName) AS PersonName`.